# getting input with fgets() in a loop

Tags: c, arrays, fgets

I am trying to take input with `fgets()`. I know how many lines I will get but it changes and I store the number of lines in the variable `var`. I also have another variable named `part`; it is the length of the line I get, but since there are white spaces between the values I multiplied it by 2 (I couldn't find another solution; I could use some advice).

Anyway, I tried to get the input as in the code below, but when I entered the first line it automatically breaks out the `for` loop and prints random things. I think it is to do with the `fgets()` in the loop; I don't know if there is a use of `fgets()` like this.

```
char inp[var][(2*part)];
int k,l;
for(k=0;k<=var;k++);
    fgets(inp[k],(2*part),stdin);
printf("%c\n",inp[0]);
printf("%c\n",inp[1]);
printf("%c\n",inp[2]);
printf("%c\n",inp[3]);
```

Comment: `%c` is for character. `inp[x]` is an *array* of `char`.

Comment: Change `%c` -> `%s`

Comment: @EugeneSh. Is it the `printf()` part problematic?

Comment: @NoWay At least the `printf` part.

Comment: `k<=var`  -->   `k < var`

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yes i just realized another one. The input i am trying to get is like `1.5 2.5 0.01 0.05` and i can't know the length of it since each of them is a character. I just know how many floats there are going to be. How should i do? A `scanf()` loop maybe?

Comment: It's `sscanf`. Check it out.

Comment: `for(k=0;k<=var;k++);` Remove last `;`

Comment: Note that you should check that `fgets()` does not return NULL, even if you think it won't.  Files can be truncated by forces outside your program, for example, and your input might fail.

Answer (score 1):

> …since there are white spaces between the values I multiplied it with 2…

If you aren't required to store everything on the stack, you can instead store the strings in dynamically allocated memory.  For example:

```
char* inp[var];
char buf[400]; // just needs to be long
for (k = 0; k < var;  k++) {
    fgets(buf, 400, stdin);
    inp[k] = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(buf) + 1));
    strcpy(inp[k], buf);
}
```

Although technically not standards-compliant, `strdup` is widely available and makes this easier as well.

As far as the actual issue, as BLUEPIXY said in the comments above, you have a few typos.

1. After the for loop, the semicolon makes it act unexpectedly.

   ```
   for(k=0;k<=var;k++);
       fgets(inp[k],(2*part),stdin);
   ```

   is actually the same as

   ```
   for(k=0;k<=var;k++) {
       ; // do nothing
   }
   fgets(...);
   ```

   Remove that semicolon after the for loop statement.  As it is, you're not actually reading correctly, which is why you see garbage.
2. To print an entire string, the `printf` family needs a `%s` format flag.
3. With your bounds on `k`, there will actually be `var + 1` iterations of the loop. If `var` were `3`, then `k = 0,1,2,3` -> terminate when `k` checked at `4`.

Comment: 1) Rather than `char buf[400]; ... fgets(buf, 400, stdin);`, consider `char buf[400]; ... fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin);`.  Then when 400 changes to 500, there is less code maintenance.  2) Robust code check the return value of `fgets()`.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, the safest and easiest way to use `fgets` is to allocate a single, large-enough line buffer. Use that to read the line, then copy it into correctly sized buffers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    // Allocate just the space for the list, not the strings themselves.
    int num_input = 5;
    char *input[num_input];

    // Allocate our reusable line buffer.
    char line[1024];
    for( int i = 0; i < num_input; i++ ) {
        // Read into the line buffer.
        fgets(line, 1024,stdin);

        // Copy from the line buffer into correctly sized memory.
        input[i] = strdup(line);
    }

    for( int i = 0; i < num_input; i++ ) {
        printf("%s\n",input[i]);
    }
}
```

Note that strdup() is not an ISO C function, but POSIX. It's common and standard enough. It's too handy not to use. Write your own if necessary.

That takes care of not knowing the line length.

---

If you don't know the number of lines you're storing, you'll have to grow the array. Typically this is done with `realloc` to reallocate the existing memory. Start with a small list size, then grow it as needed. Doubling is a good rough approximation that's a pretty efficient balance between speed (reallocating can be slow) and memory efficiency.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(void) {
    // How big the input list is.
    size_t input_max = 64;

    // How many elements are in it.
    size_t input_size = 0;

    // Allocate initial memory for the input list.
    // Again, not for the strings, just for the list.
    char **input = malloc( sizeof(char*) * input_max );

    char line[1024];
    while( fgets(line, 1024,stdin) != NULL ) {
        // Check if we need to make the input list bigger.
        if( input_size >= input_max ) {
            // Double the max length.
            input_max *= 2;

            // Reallocate.
            // Note: this is only safe because we're
            // going to exit on error, otherwise we'd leak
            // input's memory.
            input = realloc( input, sizeof(char*) * input_max );

            // Check for error.
            if( input == NULL ) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Could not reallocate input list to %zu: %s", input_max, strerror(errno) );
                exit(1);
            }
        }

        input[input_size] = strdup(line);
        input_size++;
    }

    for( size_t i = 0; i < input_size; i++ ) {
        printf("%s\n",input[i]);
    }
}
```

As you can see, this gets a bit complicated. Now you need to keep track of the array, its maximum size, and its current size. Anyone using the array must remember to check its size and grow it, and remember to error check it. Your next impulse will be to create a struct to collect all that together, and functions to manage the list.

This is a good exercise in dynamic memory management, and I encourage you to do it. But for production code, use a pre-existing library. [GLib](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/) is a good choice. It contains all sorts of handy data structures and functions that are missing from C, including [pointer arrays that automatically grow](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Pointer-Arrays.html). Use them, or something like it, in production code.

Comment: `pointer = malloc(sizeof *pointer * size)` is a nice idiom to introduce to learners with `input = malloc(sizeof *input * input_max);`   BTW: `input = realloc( input, input_max );` is too small.  Suggest `input = realloc(input, sizeof *input *  input_max);`

Comment: @chux Thanks, I'll fix it.

Comment: @Schwern I've tried all the things but it gets only the first line in the input then breaks. It doesn't even printed anything. The input i am trying to get is:   `C .065 .08 .1 .13 .2 .05 .04 .04 .03 .01 .005 .0  
A .039 .023 .016 .008 .124 .062 .031 .016 .008 .008 .008 .006  
D 0 0 0 .012 .025 .1 .2 .1 .05 .039 .025 .025  
B .022 .029 .036 .044 .051 .058 .066 .073 .080 .088 .095 .103`(I couldn't add a linebreak every line starts with a capital letter )

Comment: @NoWay If you're using the second example with `while( fgets(line, 1024,stdin) != NULL )` it doesn't know how much input to expect so it will keep waiting for more. You have to tell it its done with `ctrl-d`. Then `fgets` will read `EOF` (end of file) from `stdin` and return `NULL`.